# Is it okay to not implement exception throws in an interface implementation?

Tags: java, exception

I've made a more specific ListIterator for singly linked lists and I have implemented most of the methods. I see in the description that some methods should throw exceptions but some exceptions don't seem particularly relevant, especially as I'm using generics. Is it fine to not have  these exceptions in the implementation?

Comment: What methods? What exceptions? Not relevant why?

Comment: I was thinking ClassCastException and IllegalArgumentException wouldn't be relevant for the add method. Am I right in thinking that these wouldn't be  necessary where Im using generics?

Comment: No, because remember that generics are largely a compile-time thing. It would be entirely possible to get a raw reference to your list and put things in it that shouldn't be there, so they'll both still be applicable. They're also both `RuntimeException`s, so you don't need to declare them anyway.

Comment: Sure thing... I think I'll brush up on exceptions a bit more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fundamentally, since the `throws` isn't part of the [method signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2), if your implementation of a method doesn't throw the relevant exception, you can leave that exception off.

E.g., this is perfectly valid:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void method() throws Exception;
}
```

and

```
public class Example implements MyInterface {
    public void method() {
    }
}
```

Comment: that's true because in a logical point of view the exception is  depending on the implementation not the name of the interfaced method

Comment: @MohammedHousseynTaleb: Yup.